Spring Boot 3.3.0 Guide Fail
I setup a new Spring Boot project using Gradle 8.8 and Spring Boot 3.3.0 Gradle Plugin. From there, I followed the guide found here, making minor adjustments to the HttpSecurity bean to remove deprecations as follows:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain httpFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authCust) -> authCust
            .requestMatchers("/", "/error", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .exceptionHandling(e -> e
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
        )
        .csrf(c -> c
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        )
        .logout(logoutCust -> logoutCust
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        )
        .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
        
    return http.build();
}

I also copied the index.html directly from the guide GitHub repo, which looks like this:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>Demo</title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<base href="/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div class="container unauthenticated">
        <div>
            With GitHub: <a href="/oauth2/authorization/github">click here</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            With Microsoft: <a href="/oauth2/authorization/microsoft">click here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container authenticated" style="display: none">
        Logged in as: <span id="user"></span>
        <div>
            <button onClick="logout()" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/js-cookie/js.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend : function(xhr, settings) {
              if (settings.type == 'POST' || settings.type == 'PUT'
                  || settings.type == 'DELETE') {
                if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/
                    .test(settings.url))) {
                  // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", Cookies
                      .get('XSRF-TOKEN'));
                }
              }
            }
          });
          $.get("/user", function(data) {
              $("#user").html(data.name);
              $(".unauthenticated").hide();
              $(".authenticated").show();
          });
          var logout = function() {
            $.post("/logout", function() {
              $("#user").html('');
              $(".unauthenticated").show();
              $(".authenticated").hide();
            })
            return true;
          }
        </script>
</body>
</html>

And here is my build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
}

sourceCompatibility = 17
targetCompatibility = 17

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

group = "design.ore"
version = "2.0.0"
mainClassName = "design.ore.cORE.Main"
def packagename = "cORE"
def ore3DAPIVersion = "2.1.22"
def oreNetBridgeVersion = "1.0.2"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26"
    
    implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310"
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.13.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.webjars:jquery:3.7.1'
    implementation 'org.webjars:bootstrap:5.3.3'
    implementation 'org.webjars:js-cookie:3.0.1'
    implementation 'org.webjars:webjars-locator-core'
    
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    
    // Use local instance of API if available
    if (findProject(':Ore3D-API') != null)
    {
        implementation (project(":Ore3D-API")) {
            exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        }
    }
    else
    {
        implementation ("com.github.Ore-Design:Ore3D-API:${ore3DTargetVersion}") {
            exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        }
    }
    
    // Use local instance of OreNetBridge if available
    if (findProject(':OreNetBridge') != null)
    {
        implementation (project(":OreNetBridge")) {
            exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        }
    }
    else
    {
        implementation ("com.github.Ore-Design:OreNetBridge:${oreNetBridgeVersion}") {
            exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        }
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': "${mainClassName}",
        'Plugin-Id': "${packagename}",
        'Plugin-Version': "${version}",
        'Plugin-Provider': "${group}",
        'Ore3D-API-Version': "${ore3DAPIVersion}",
        'OreNetBridge-Version': "${oreNetBridgeVersion}",
        'Plugin-Dependencies': ""
    }
}

When I got to http:localhost:8080, I am greeted by a 401 HTTP Exception.
If I remove the CSRF portion of the HTTP filter chain, I get automatically get redirected to the Spring Boot auto-generated login page, instead of index.html
Thanks in advance for the help :D

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but if you want to make endpoints "/", "/error", "/webjars/**" available for everyone without authentication, then below solution could work for you. I don't have a project configured with oauth2Login to test it, but i had similar issue with oauth2ResourceServer.
Try to make another filter chain for your unprotected paths only with higher precedence (@Order annotation) that will disable oauth2Login:
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain httpFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authCust) -> authCust
                .requestMatchers("/", "/error", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
        )
        .oauth2Login(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

    return http.build();
}

You can add more configuration options (like csrf etc.) if you want.
